# CSS selector to match an element that doesn't have background-color applied inline

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors

Is there a way to select an element that **doesn't** have a certain CSS property applied **inline** (independently of the value)?

```
.element:not([background-color^="rgb"]){}

.element:[background-color=""]{}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) is the **style** not the [CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/) (background-color in this case).

-Using the **CSS3 [attribute^=value] Selector**, the value begins with the word ("background-color"):

```
.element:not([style^="background-color"]){}
```

---

-Using the **CSS [attribute~="value"] Selector**, the value contains a specified word ("background-color:"), in any part of the value, but the whole word:

```
.element:not([style~="background-color:"]){}
```

---

-Using the **CSS [attribute|="value"] Selector**, the value has to be a whole word, either alone, like class="top", or followed by a hyphen( - ):

```
.element:not([style|="background"]){}
```

---

-Using the **CSS [attribute*="value"] Selector**, the value contains a specified value (letters), in any part of it:

```
.element:not([style*="background"]){}
```